# Connecting to AWS using SDK for .Net

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

What are the different ways with which I can access an AWS service (let's just use S3 as an example here) through .Net code from an application that does not run on AWS?

Provided I have an IAM user that has the appropriate role to access S3:

1. Store the access id / secret access key in the app.config and access through that
2. Authenticate the user on premises, set up STS and use that to get temporary security credentials from AWS and then access S3.

Is there any other method? Instance metadata or EC2 instance profile works only on EC2 running in AWS isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The AWS .NET SDK documentation covers credentials over at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html.

You can use a credentials file stored on the server, similar to how aws-cli stores credentials. If you already have the cli installed on the box, I believe the SDK will try and use the default profile automatically.

Alternatively, you can also use the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` etc. environment variables.